# What's the reasoning behind "part" and "part of" in Dart libraries?

Tags: dart

I was wondering what the reasoning is behind the way libraries and their content are defined. More specifically, a library needs to list all parts and the parts need to state the library of which they are part.

This bidirection seems unnecessary to me and I would expect that a reference from the library to the parts would be enough. Also, when adding or removing files from libraries, there are 2 places where modifications need to be made.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Because the library is not exactly what many people think. The library in Dart is not a module. I found just one explanation about what are a library. This sounds like `"Libraries are units of privacy"`. No more and no less.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have not seen this specifically addressed anywhere, but I have wondered about this as well, and the conclusion I've come to is that it's a symptom of using library level privacy as opposed to class level privacy.

If a library only needed to list its parts then you could gain access to any library's internal properties simply by declaring it a part:

```dart
library hax;

part 'packages/somelib/secret.dart';
```

I now have access to any private field or method in secret.dart. I can do this with any third-party package I've imported, making the concept of privacy a joke.

Similarly, if only a `part of` declaration was required, any file could inject itself into a library by declaring that it was part of that library.

However, by requiring both a `part` declaration in the file declaring the library, and a `part of` declaration in the file that is to be included in the library, Dart avoids this situation.

Comment: That makes sense indeed. I never thought of it this way.

Comment: With `part of` referencing to a name one can include the part in several libraries if those libraries have the same name. See this [message from Kasper Lund](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/dqKNiPmxkQQ/wDCuf-l8XFoJ).

Comment: While this answer raises an interesting point, private members are not about secrecy.  Access control is more about defining an API.  It is not intended to and cannot stop a developer determined to subvert the code.  Many packages put private implementation in `src/` subdirectories and rely  only on suggestion to not `import` them directly.  Furthermore, since the code to packages is necessarily available, anyone can always copy and paste the package's source code and modify it.

Answer (score 5):

You can find some informations in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/OLTlR7aIOP4).

From Gilad Bracha :

> Originally, parts were not tied to their libraries. People complained because it was difficult to give good tool support (i.e., what scope are you in when you open a part but not a library that uses it?).

Comment: From Gilad answer is not clear which people complained. People that want to write the good tool support? Or people that want to have the good tool support?

Comment: Thanks for the reference Alexandre.