# Dart editor: expected url

Tags: dart

I have this error :

```
  Internal error: 'http://127.0.0.1:3030/Motion/bin/csscode.dart': error: line 2 pos 6: url expected
part of dart.motion;
```

This part is next motion.dart library;
what is the problem ?

I have trouble getting the Dart editor find the files that are part of the libraries, and the libraries themselves. Anyone know where to find detailed information about this topic?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the reasoning behind "part" and "part of" in Dart libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403551/whats-the-reasoning-behind-part-and-part-of-in-dart-libraries)

Answer (score 4):

Notice that this error could happen when a "***part of*** file" is loaded instead of its ***library***.

For example, from a `<script>` tag in a custom-element/page:

```html
<script type="application/dart" src="my-part-library.dart"></script><!--won't works-->
<script type="application/dart" src="TheLibrary.dart"></script><!--will works-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out to be an issue with file encoding.