# Can't get Library in Dart to work properly

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have some files and I want them in one library. But it just doesnt work or throws Exceptions.

Let's say I have these files.
Lib.dart, 1.dart, 2.dart, 3.dart and for each of them also an html file, which defines the polymer element.

```dart
// Lib.dart
library testLib;

import 'dart:html';

part '1.dart';
part '2.dart';
part '3.dart';

/* ... Code ... */
```

and

```dart
// 1.dart 2.dart and 3.dart
part of testLib;

/* ... Code ... */
```

It didnt work and i got the message:

```dart
'http://localhost:8080/1.dart': error: line 7 pos 6: url expected
part of testLib;
     ^: http://localhost:8080/1.dart
```

So I saw this answer: [Dart editor: expected url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628230/dart-editor-expected-url)

and I changed my 1.html, 2.html and 3.html to:

```dart
//  1.html, 2.html and 3.html
/* ... */
<script type="application/dart" src="Lib.dart"></script>
```

But now i get this Exception:

```dart
Breaking on exception: Already registered (Polymer) prototype for element my-Lib
```

I dont know why it does not work or what I did wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why your `part of` is on line 7. Do you have a library statement or imports or other code above `par of`? You can only have comments before `part of`.

As far as I know currently there is still the limitation that you should have one library for one polymer element.

Comment: There are Comments before the part of.  So i should just use one lib for each polymer element?

Comment: Yes as far as I know there is still only one element per library supported.