# Import issue - libraries should not have the same name

Tags: dart

I am trying to build a library that currently has the following structure

```
lib
 | src (contains some internal .dart files)
 |  | private_parts.dart
 | strategies (contains sample strategies for applications)
 |  | scoring.dart
 |  | time.dart
 | mylib.dart (the main library file to include)
```

My problem occurs when I try to write an application that uses the sample strategies. I get the error/warning `The imported libraries 'scoring.dart' and 'time.dart' should not have the same name ''`.

My main file looks something like this (placed in the web folder)

```dart
import 'package:mylib/mylib.dart';
import 'package:mylib/strategies/scoring.dart';
import 'package:mylib/strategies/time.dart';

main() {
    game = new Engine(new StandardTime(), new StandardScoring());
}
```

How should I restructure the library to make it correct? What is best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't show a library directive so I suppose more than one library has the library name 'NONE'.

Add a library directive at the top of your dart source file

```dart
library my_library.my_sublibrary; // <= this should differ for each library
```

In dart each source file is a library as long as you don't add

```dart
part of some_library
```

instead of the library directive. Adding no `library` or `part of` directive makes it implicitely a library without a name.

Comment: Only the `mylib.dart` has the library directive. All files in `src` are parts. So you are saying that I should add a library directive to each of the strategies? Is the "dot syntax" the regular way to do it?

Comment: Then you didn't set up the `part` `part of` relation correctly
(you didn't provide enough code to make this obvious). After you dothis you only need to import `mylib.dart`. Probably you are missing the `part 'strategies/scoring.dart'; part 'stategies/time.dart';` directives in your `mylib.dart` file.
see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403551

Comment: The strategies does not have the `part` relation with `mylib.dart`. I wanted to make them separate as they are not part of the "core" library, but more like sample implementations of some core interfaces. I think I will just add them as parts for now. Thank you for your help.